# how to auto ignore group exists when send data into redis stream in rust

Tags: rust, redis

I want to auto create group before send data into redis stream, so I write my rust code like this:

```
use std::env;

use redis::{Commands, PubSubCommands, ControlFlow, RedisError};
use rust_wheel::config::cache::redis_util::get_con;

fn main() {
    push_to_stream("texhub-server:proj:s-comp-queue", "test", &[("name", "test")]);
}

pub fn push_to_stream(
    stream_key: &str,
    group: &str,
    params: &[(&str, &str)],
) -> Result<String, RedisError> {
    env::set_var("REDIS_URL", "redis://default:123456@127.0.0.1:6379/1");
    let mut connection = get_con();
    let g_result =
        connection.xgroup_create_mkstream::<&str, &str, &str, String>(stream_key, group, "$");
    if let Err(e) = g_result.as_ref() {
        println!(
            "create group failed,{},stream key: {}, group: {}",
            e, stream_key, group
        );
        return g_result;
    }
    connection.xadd::<&str, &str, &str, &str, String>(stream_key, "*", params)
}
```

now I am facing a error that when the group exists, the `xgroup_create_mkstream` will run into error:

```
push to stream failed,BUSYGROUP: Consumer Group name already exists
```

Am I doing the right way? should I just ignore the error? I think ignore the group name exists error is not a good practice. What should I do to handle this issue? this is my Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "rust-learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rust_wheel = { git = "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/rust_wheel.git", branch = "diesel2.0", features = ["model","common","rwconfig"]}
redis = "0.21.3"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69507919/175554 may help